# How to use Angular app from another website

Tags: angular

1. I have my Angular application that is hosted at [www.A.com](http://www.A.com),
2. My customer has a web site that is hosted at [www.B.com](http://www.B.com)
3. I need to let my customer to insert the Angular app on his webpage **without copying** application files to his website. I want my customer to just add some HTML code that references the files from my original [www.A.com](http://www.A.com) website.

So, at some page `www.B.com/somepage.html` customer would put something like that:

```
<base href="https://www.A.com" />
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.469fa17746b90e8a757c.js" defer></script>
<script src="polyfills.35a5ca1855eb057f016a.js" defer></script>
<script src="scripts.3cf90f8fc92130239739.js" defer></script>
<script src="main.f229882672708596d13b.js" defer></script>
```

I tried this approach but encountered with a whole bunch of issues related to CORS and CORB.

Does anyone have a clear path on how a webpage can use Angular app from another domain?

**EDIT NOTE 1:**
solution with **iframe does not work for us** because it negatively affects SEO (Google penalizes us for  it), so we cannot use iframe with external link on our website.

**EDIT NOTE 2:**
I have ownership of [www.A.com](http://www.A.com) (so I can adjust any configuration/HTTP headers required for my app to be used from external websites)

Comment: Your requirement doesn't seems feasible, its feature of Angular to prevent injection from outside world

Comment: @Romesh - to my knowledge there is no such specific feature in Angular. can you please add a proof (documentation url) for your claim? thanks.

Comment: you can try using the other page as an iframe

Comment: @Lord Midi, why did you delete your answer? your idea was the closest to the solution

Answer (score 6):

We can Do it in multiple ways

1. You can use subdomain, to point the other project,
2. You can use the Iframe, to load it and style it.
3. You can make your one Application as a Independent Module and make it as NPM Module and use it in another Application.

Comment: thanks for the effort @Mahesh but let me comment your points: 1) I do not control customer's domain (subdomains). I need to retain my app on my independent domain. 2) iframe is not good solution for public website due to SEO penalty by Google. 3) Module will be coped into main app during the build stage and then copied to the customer's website, so there is no reusability from original location.

Answer (score 1):

By using Angular Elements you can package Angular component as Web Component, a web standard for defining new HTML elements in a framework-agnostic way.

https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score 1):

Were you compiling the application with the --base-href flag pointing to the client application domain?

```
ng build --prod --base-href www.B.com
```

In this way, the application will be based on the client's domain, and maybe(i never try before) you can access [www.B.com/[ruta](http://www.B.com/%5Bruta) that you define in angular routing as input to the app}

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** make a functional page or element by putting *some lines of Angular client-side rendered codes* on the fly. They are meaningful for the Angular app. In case of successful injection regarding default Angular configurations, the main script's hash changes every time you build the project.

Best way regarding `iframe` avoidance is creating a [web component using angular](https://angular.io/guide/elements) so that you can later use that element anywhere by just importing a single file. In this way, this is recommended to reuse **simple** components, not a whole functional page for a **perfect working** and **secure** (prevent [phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing)) project. There's a good and brief sample [Using Angular component in Non-Angular App](https://dev.to/maulik/using-angular-component-in-non-angular-app-1p0g). More professional considerations using web components listed inside [Why I don't use web components](https://dev.to/richharris/why-i-don-t-use-web-components-2cia) which I agree with Rich Harris.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the concept of micro-front-ends come into picture. This is the exact scenario.

Now this can be done in n number of ways. One of which is Angular Elements.

Angular provides you an option to make your application into a web-element, which can be included into another index.html file as a main.js file.

You can read more about it here:

How to make angular elements: https://angular.io/guide/elements

What is micro-front-end and how to use it:
Method 1) Use a framework called SPA (single page application)
you can read about it here: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/microfrontends-concept

Example:

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { PopupService } from './popup.service';
import { PopupComponent } from './popup.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input #input value="Message">
    <button (click)="popup.showAsComponent(input.value)">Show as component</button>
    <button (click)="popup.showAsElement(input.value)">Show as element</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {


/************* 
This particular constructor will make your component into an angular element there-by allowing you to use this as a main.js file once you compile it and put it in a SPA page or however you want to use it
**************/

  constructor(injector: Injector, public popup: PopupService) {
    // Convert `PopupComponent` to a custom element.
    const PopupElement = createCustomElement(PopupComponent, {injector});
    // Register the custom element with the browser.
    customElements.define('popup-element', PopupElement);
  }
}
```